Why do I have this execution sequence in a Vue 3 program?
I am working on a project with Vue 3, Vuetify 3 and Pinia. Out of simple curiousity, I put a console.log() statement at the start of the following files in my project: main.ts, App.vue, Tracker.ts (my Pinia store), and the first line of the scripts for each component. I was quite surprised to see that the first of the statements to execute was the one in Tracker.ts, my Pinia store. The rest of the sequence seemed logical: main.ts, App.vue, then each of the components in the order they were rendered from the top to the bottom.
Can anyone explain why the Pinia store was the first to execute? I honestly expected it to be executed only when the first component accessed it.
I'm not losing sleep about this but I am curious about it. Understanding this may help me understand Vue better.

Because the Pinia store is imported by the maints,and the import statement get promoting.
